# Entity Framework 6, database-first with ORACLE in MVC 5.2.3 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework-6

can someone help me with this error ?
[image: Error after set up connection string and confirm]

I using MVC 5.2.3 and .NET 4.6. I have installed ODAC 12c Release 4 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.1.0.2.4) from oracle official website here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html, added NuGet packages Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework

and that generate this providers in webconfig file:

```
  <configSections>    
<section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

```
<provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

Does anyone get this work ? What i'm missing ? Thanks for every hint

Comment: Include all references of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` and related dependencies into your project, then try using EDM Wizard again. Note that you may need to change target active platform into x86 with rebuild solution before retry the wizard.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the Entity Framework Oracle provider. You can do that in two ways:

1. In the Package Manager Console execute the following command:

   Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework
2. Follow the instruction for NuGet ODP.NET Installation and Configuration from here

[Using NuGet to Install and Configure Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/NuGet/index.html)

Comment: I'm still not able to get this work.. After all step i finally create EDMX model, but only in webapplication project where the controllers are, but i need to create model in my class library project, which is working as repository layer. There i'wll get provider error. Note: That i have installed Oracle.ManagedDriver (+ Entity FrameWorkDriver) also to this project and also add references.

Comment: You should be able to add the EDMX model in a class library project without problems. Just need to verify that all the necessary packages are installed in the project and, probably, add a config file (app.config) with the entity framework sections to the class library project. I recommend that you compare the config files and package.config files for the web application and class library to see that there are no missing packages/configuration in the class library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I do not mistake i need include packages Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework. Those two I have in both projects. packages.config files seems to be fine (same). Those two packages are in both files and also package EntityFramework. I have App.Config file in class library project and instalation of NuGet packages did all changes. There is an entityFramework section with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client provider. Do you have any other tips why creation of EDMX model works in webapp project and doesn't in class library project ?

Comment: Just made a 2 minute test (just to be sure). The required packages for the class library project are: EntityFramework, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework. Adding this dependencies to the class library, nuget will generate an app.config file with the necessary config info in the dll project. Just remember that you need 2 config files: an app.config in the dll project containing the info necessary for the edmx generation at design time and a web.config file used at runtime by the web.app. for db interactions.